# regex replace element text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Never seem to master those regex's...

I need to update the total with newVal

```
<span class="myClass">some text Total (12)</span>
```

into

```
<span class="myClass">some text Total (13)</span>
```

and also without a current value

```
<span class="myClass">some text Total</span>
```

into

```
<span class="myClass">some text Total (13)</span>
```

oh, and some text can be anything

my code

```
    newVal = 13;
    $('.myClass').text( $('.myClass').text().replace(???, ???) );
```

Comment: Which regexes have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong approach, your code would only return the new string. To set it, use

```
$('.myClass').text(function(i, old){ 
   return old.replace(/(\s+\(\d+\))?$/, " ("+newVal+")");
})
```

The regex matches the string end, and (optionally) whitespaces + bracketed number before.

Comment: It does only delete the " (12)" in the end, which you want to have replaced, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap counters with `span`:

```
<span class="myClass">some text Total (<span>12</span>)</span>
```

and do like so:

```
newVal = 13;
$('.myClass span').text(newVal);
```

Comment: Sorry, need to do it without wrapping the counter.